# Master list of all NuGet Version to .NET Framework to AssemblyVersionAttribute mappings?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard

Is there a master list somewhere of all the odd NuGet version to Assembly version mappings?  This is VERY confusing trying to upgrade old applications and debugging `FileLoadException` errors that ocur when Assembly Fusion runs.  I have found a [master matrix of all .NET Standard versions to .NET implementation versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-platforms-support), but nothing at the package-level.

Background for those unfamiliar:

1. Run `Install-Package System.ComponentModel.Annotations -Version 4.5.0` or add this package to an empty .NET Standard or .NET Core project template in Visual Studio
2. Load your target framework's DLL and then grab the FullName:

   ```
   $path = "C:\source\Infrastructure\SqlClone\Source\Company.Database.SqlCloneTask\packages\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.4.5.0\lib\net461\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll"
   $assembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom($path)
   $assembly.FullName
   ```

   This returns:
   `System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a`
3. Then using the Version=4.2.10 and PublicKeyTooken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a to generate an [runtime.assemblyBinding.dependentAssembly.bindingRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element):

   ```
   <runtime>
     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.2.1.0" />
       </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
   ```

The above steps are the only way I have found to reliably fix `FileLoadException` errors with `bindingRedirect` configurations, without using Google Search and finding a StackOverflow answer or GitHub issue :). Even right clicking Properties on the file and going to the Details tab shows:

- File version: 4.6.26515.6
- Product version: 4.6.26515.06 @BuiltBy: dlab-DDVSOWINAGE059 @ Branch: release/2.1 @SrcCode: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/30ab651fcb4354552bd4891619a0bdd81e0ebdbf

Example errors (should help Google Search results):

1. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
2. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
3. 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, 
   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one 
   of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
4. Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection That's why automatic binding redirection is added.

Comment: Hmm... (a) wow, I did not know about that feature (b) if that's the case, why are there so many newer GitHub issues and StackOverflow questions about FileLoadException errors asking about .NET Standard and .NET Core? Also, do you know where in common.targets this trickery is defined?

Comment: VS2017 15.8 for the very first time makes this option visible in project settings page, after its introduction for years. I believe that's exactly why there are so many issues reported, the laziness of the creator.

Comment: Wait, so the default, if unspecified, is false? The MS Docs make it sound like the default is true? See: "Automatic binding redirects are enabled by default for traditional desktop apps that target the .NET Framework 4.5.1 and later versions." The wording here is rather cumbersome, as it is unclear what the scope of "traditional desktop apps" is.

Comment: @LexLi Found this interesting - apparently there are two properties you might need to set to true: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1310#issuecomment-300155346

Comment: @LexLi, Auto-generated binding redirects don't work for Azure Functions, and you still have to have a way to track this stuff down to manually configure the Function App in Azure.

Comment: @Toby It sounds like you are a programmer after my own heart.  This stuff gets really complicated.  If you want to discuss more, find me on gitter.im/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator